# [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'headers.Authorization = "Bearer " + userToken')]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a generic Api for my app, I am setting headers.authorization to Bearer+token but its not working. I checked by consoling userToken it displays fine there, but can not really update headers with it...  need a little push here :)

```
export default async (url, method, token, body) => {
 let headers;
  if (token) {
    const userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
    headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${userToken}`;
  }

  const structure = {
    url,
    method,
    headers,
  };
```

Comment: The error message is telling you that `userToken` is null. Can you `console.log(userToken)` then what that value really is? The `token` must not exist yet so you should make it at least an empty string I'm guessing.

Comment: change it to `let headers = {}`

Comment: Love you bro it worked...... :)